# babel-node with typescript throws "Cannot use import statement outside a module" in command line

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs

So, I saw many similar issues, but most of them refer to built code, and this one is actually a CLI script.

My command is:
`node_modules/.bin/babel-node -x .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx scripts/database/index.ts generate`

And if it calls some code from `node_modules` (`React Native` related to be precise) it will throw the error.

I tried `type: module` but it caused even worse errors.

babel.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-flow',
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types'],
    [
      require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),
      {
        root: ['.'],
        extensions: [
          '.ios.js',
          '.android.js',
          '.js',
          '.ts',
          '.tsx',
          '.json',
          // '.png',
        ],
        alias: {
          app: ['./app'],
          'test/*': ['test/'],
          '@components': './app/components',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  sourceMaps: true,
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["ES2016"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["app/*"],
      "tests": ["tests/*"],
    },
    // ensure ignores node_modules
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "@wdio/types",
      "webdriverio/async",
      // "@wdio/jasmine-framework",
      // "expect-webdriverio/jasmine",
      "jest"
    ]
  },
  // "include": [
  //   "src/*",
  //   "tests/*",
  // ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js",
    // isnores special cases
    "**/modules/**",
    "node_modules/react-native/**",
    "node_modules/@react-navigation/**",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `"type": "module"`

install `@babel/register`

in your very first line of code, add this line
`require('@babel/register')({ extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] })`

npm script
`"start": "babel-node -x js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx -- src/app.ts"`

update:

turn out that you can skip the whole `@babel/register` thing, what you are missing is a `--` in your command

Comment: I finally had the time to try it, but sadly it triggers `Cannot use import statement outside a module` when I use the `import` statement. I also tried adding `"type": "module"` back, but then it doesn't recognize the `.ts` extension...

Comment: @SidFerreira https://dev.to/tylim88/babel-node-typescript-minus-ts-node-efa

Answer (score 0):

Woof this was rough.

I recently started gradually adopting TS into my Node app and I thought that was the cause.

But I'm starting to think the default option for the `--config` in `babel-node` is no longer looking for `babel.config.js` and rather only looking for `babel.config.json`.

I painstakingly converted my babel config to JSON and that *seems* to have fixed.

Also, the `--extensions` argument **must** include `.ts`. So to support both `.js` and `.ts` files in the same project you need to define this:

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "task": "babel-node --extensions .js,.ts -- ",
}
```

`babel.config.json`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./"],
        "alias": {
          "test": "./__test__"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Then finally I was able to execute CLI commands like so:

`yarn task something.js`

or

`yarn task something.ts`

Answer (score 0):

This is the bare minimum solution that worked for me:

**babel.config.json**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript", "@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/node": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.5",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node --extensions .js,.ts,.json -- src/app.ts"
  },
}
```